# Trying to copy 2 dependencies in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to copy 2 dependencies in my makefile, but only the first one is getting copied. Here is my code:

```
CODE_SOURCE := i_code.c s_code.c
$(CODE_SOURCE): $(addprefix $(MY_PATH)/lib/mods/,$(CODE_SOURCE))
   $(CP) $< $@
```

But I see that only the first file is being copied. How do I get both these file in my current dir?

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
%: $(MY_PATH)/lib/mods/%
    $(CP) $< $@

<whatever depends on these files>: $(CODE_SOURCE)
```

This will attempt to copy files from `/lib/mods`, if they exist, to fulfill the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pattern (or static pattern) rule here to do what you want.

Something like this (untested) [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(CODE_SOURCE) : % : $(MY_PATH)/lib/mods/%
        $(CP) $< $@
```

Comment: $^ is generating a copy command like so:
`cp /libs/mods/i_code.c /libs/mods/s_code.c i_code.c` and this gives a copy error..

Comment: Ah. I see. I didn't look at what you were doing carefully enough. You want something more like nneonneo's answer. A pattern rule.